# Bash Scripting Run from rc.local

Tags: linux, bash

I have made a script that uses a program called Diascope, its a video slideshow program.

I am trying to run this command in encodeVideo.sh

```
echo "Running diascope -clean /mnt/videos/video$1.txt..."
diascope -clean /mnt/videos/video$1.txt > /var/www/html/video/encodeVideo.log
echo "Removing old deploy dir, and making new one..."
```

And I am running this script from rc.local so that it runs every time I boot the instance.

**All I need is to get the output of the "diascope" command**, in rc.local I run encodeVideo:

```
/bin/bash /var/www/html/video/encodeVideo.sh > /var/www/html/video/newlog
```

and in newlog I can see this

```
Running diascope -clean /mnt/videos/video7.txt...
Removing old deploy dir, and making new one...
```

and /var/www/html/video/encodeVideo.log is completely empty! Diascope uses gawk, and btw I can see the output of the processing when I manually run the encodeVideo.sh script. Why can I not capture it in this log?

Is it possible that it's not standard output, so ">" doesn't actually capture it?

Any ideas would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try redirecting **stderr** and **stdout** to filename

```
diascope -clean /mnt/videos/video$1.txt 1> /var/www/html/video/encodeVideo.log  2>&1
```

Comment: @glennjackman So this command `diascope -clean /mnt/videos/video$1.txt 1> /var/www/html/video/encodeVideo.log  2>&1` would be the same as `diascope -clean /mnt/videos/video$1.txt &> /var/www/html/video/encodeVideo.log` (in bash)?

Comment: @SSHThis, yes -- see section 3.6.4 under http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible that it's not standard output, so ">" doesn't actually capture it?

Absolutely: it could be standard error, in which case you'd have to use `2>` instead of `>`.